# Why do molecular modelling simulations predict that halobromides are more stable than halochlorides?

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry

The C-Cl  bond energy is greater than that of C-Br, yet the minimised energy of say, methyl bromide is larger (more negative) than methyl chloride. I've tried using STO 6G, HF 3-21G, and 6-21G*, all show similar trends.

Comment: This sort of comparison is unreliable. "More stable" is a pretty subjective term and should only be used when comparing two otherwise equal situations: for example a reaction that produces two different isomers. One might be more stable and formed preferentially. The minimized energy is related to the heat of formation, and we should expect different heats of formation for the two species. Instead, if we compare the reactions of both compounds with the same reagent to make a common product, then we could talk about "relative stability", but "relative reactivity" is a better term.

Comment: What kind of energies are you comparing? Absolute energies as obtained from Hartree-Fock? Do a calculation of a single Br atom and then of a single Cl atom, you might notice that you obtain a much larger energy for the Br atom. Please tell us what energies you are comparing and what methods you are using. Quantum chemical calculations are dangerous as in if you do not know what you're doing, your results are meaningless. Do not interpret anything into your calculation please.

Answer (score 6):

The absolute energy of different molecules is irrelevant because they have a different number of particles (electrons and protons); the one with more particles (C-Br in your case) will typically display a more negative energy.

Thus, one must compute relative energies using systems with the same number of particles. For example, you could compare the energy of CH$_3$Cl + Br$^-$ with that of CH$_3$Br + Cl$^-$.